# Is there a guide on exactly how to report outputs (regression, anova, correspondence analysis) in APA?

Tags: analysis, regression, apa-style

I would like to report statistical findings after quantitative data analysis in APA format. Is there a guide on this? I've not been able to find any.

I'm using SPSS but I'm sure it would be similar in SData and R.

Answer (score 4):

You should get the [APA Style Manual (currently in the 6th edition)](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=apa+style+manual+pdf&oq=apa+style+manual+pdf).

> Chapter 5 describes the effective use of graphic elements in text. It provides readers with guidance on which graphic element is best suited to the data being delivered as well as detailed instruction on table and figure preparation.

It has lots of examples of how to report individual statistics and how to present common analyses in tabular form (e.g., group differences, correlation matrices, regression models, multilevel models, SEM results, etc.)

For less common analyses, you can often use the tables provided in the manual as a a starting point. You may also like to search the literature for example publications.